# Attributes not showing on configurable product

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product

I am trying to follow [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-configurable-products-magento-ecommerce-site/) guide to `create some configurable products, however the attributes are not showing on the new product page when I am creating it.`
I created an attribute `called colour_suit`. Below are the options I used.
[image]

After creating the attribute I created an attribute set called Suits and added the colour_suits attribute to it (below SKU).
[image]

Next I set the Attribute Set to Suits and Product Type to Configurable Product and I the checkbox beside Suits colour and then clicked Continue. I don't see the Suit colour option below the SKU field.
[image]

I have disabled the cache management and flushed the Magento Cache and Flash Storage. I even logged out and back in and it still doesn't show up.

If I create a Simple Product with the Attribute set Suits it will show the Suits Colour option this time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Configurable attributes**, like you `colour_suit`, are only used on the simple products.

You create **simple products** with configurable attributes. You then create a **configurable product** and associated those simple products. Now, your configurable product has those configurable options from the simple products.